# How do I set background colour and drawString without cancelling the other out in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to create a jframe and set a background colour, but also putting in a drawstring. It seems like whenever I use .add, the text appears, but not the background. Without the .add, the background changes, but not the text. 
`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Test extends JPanel{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 500);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("Hello", 300, 900);
        }public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        jf.getContentPane().add(new Test());
        jf.setSize(1920,1024);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Call `setOpaque(false)` on the `Test` class to make it transparent

Comment: Don't call setOpaque(false) on the panel. There is no reason to do this and it will  make painting less efficient. Just set the background of the panel and do proper painting on the panel by overriding `paintComponent(...)` and invoking `super.paintComponent(...)`.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples you can download. The demo code will have a better program structure for you to follow. The tutorial also contains other basic Swing information and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do this...

## You could..

Make the `Test` panel the content panel for the frame...

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
jf.setContentPane(new Test());
jf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
jf.setSize(1920, 1024);
jf.setVisible(true);
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

## You could...

Make the `Test` panel transparent

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
Test test = new Test();
test.setOpaque(false);
jf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
jf.add(test);
jf.setSize(1920, 1024);
jf.setVisible(true);
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

## You could...

Just set the background color of the `Test` panel

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
Test test = new Test();
test.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
jf.add(test);
jf.setSize(1920, 1024);
jf.setVisible(true);
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Regardless of which you do...

## You Should...

- Call the `super` method of the `paint` method
- Prefer `paintComponent` of `paint` - it's just a lot safer
- Only manipulate the UI from the context of the Event Dispatching Thead

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 500);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("Hello", 300, 900);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame jf = new JFrame();
                jf.setContentPane(new Test());
                jf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                jf.setSize(1920, 1024);
                jf.setVisible(true);
                jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the background color of the Test JPanel, **not** the JFrame.

Also:

- Override paintComponent, **not** paint
- Don't forget to call the super's painting method within your override
- Learn and follow Java naming and code formatting conventions. Your code is hard to read and understand as it is currently written.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.getContentPane().add(new MyTest("Hello", Color.RED));
        jf.pack();
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyTest extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 1600;
    private static final int PREF_H = 900;
    private static final Color BG = Color.YELLOW;
    private static final Font FONT = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 500);;
    private String text;
    private Color color;

    MyTest(String text, Color color) {
        this.text = text;
        setBackground(BG);
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setFont(FONT);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawString("Hello", 300, 600);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

}
```